# airflow connection command error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: bash, airflow

I'm upgrading to Airflow 2. From the below code in my entrypoint.sh, I had `airflow connections --delete --conn_id`, but I've changed it to the below according to the docs (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html)

Now I'm getting the following error for each connection:

> airflow command error: unrecognized arguments: airflow_db airflow.. aws_default... azure_container_instances_default .. azure_cosmos_default

```
 delete_default_connections() {
      declare -a DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS=(
        "airflow_db"
        "aws_default"
        "azure_container_instances_default"
        "azure_cosmos_default"
      )
       for CONN in "${DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS[@]}"   do
    su -c "airflow connections delete conn_id $CONN" airflow   done }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the command to the following, `conn_id` is a positional argument.

```sh
 delete_default_connections() {
      declare -a DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS=(
        "airflow_db"
        "aws_default"
        "azure_container_instances_default"
        "azure_cosmos_default"
      )
       for CONN in "${DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS[@]}"   do
    su -c "airflow connections delete $CONN" airflow   done }
```